# All my projects in eclipse are showing error?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I opened my eclipse SDK and there all my projects are showing some sort of error. It is showing error in the java files. Even the imports are throwing error.. Please help me with this....!

I even tried restarting it several times.

Comment: Try open "Problems" window this will show exact error.

Comment: Try to `clean` your projects.

Comment: there must be error loading in SDK..try to restart your eclipse and wait to load all SDK data..it may help you

Comment: I am just guessing whenever that happens in eclipse it could mean that you are missing some sort of jar files.

Comment: this is the error show in problems 

But how will all my projects show error at the same time ???


"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'. styles.xml /AllAppsActivity/res/values-v14 line 8 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: See the Build in your project and whether you would hav mentioned wrong path for jar files. Or you can try that just update your SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check in Configure Build Path -> Android and check which android version is selected and check whether your application manifest has same sdkversion specified in this path or not.If not same then select sdk version that you have given in manifest and rebuild your code.

Comment: Thanks to all.I tried many things but the error seem to be the same.I reinstalled my eclipseSDK and imported all my projects again.Now they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to change as below inside your project manifest file.

instead of

**android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"**

add

**@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar**

ie, android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

This will fix it..

Comment: No use it still shows error . 
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files line 1 Java Problem

Comment: the above chang solved my issue for error : "No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'"  try cleaning all projects and also try to import the projects into a new workspace rather than existing one, i m not sure

Comment: Thanks to all.I tried many things but the error seem to be the same.I reinstalled my eclipseSDK and imported all my projects again.Now they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your SDK, check whether you have a valid JRE and JDK path defined in Java Build Path. Check whether all your dependencies are all updated and properly linked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-installing Eclipse try changing your current Workspace directory and importing all your projects there.